# Pass auth token from Django to React/Redux frontend

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, redux, django-rest-framework

My situation is kind of unique. The website I'm working on originally used Django for both frontend and backend. Now, the Django website is also being used as a backend for a React/Redux frontend, and also uses the default Django token authentication for API calls. This is all fine so far. The problem is, I'm trying to make sure the React/Redux application doesn't load unless the user is logged in on the Django website first. Basically you would have to login to the Django website first, in order to access the React/Redux application, otherwise you would be redirected back to the login screen of the Django application.

I'm wondering if there is a way to send the current user's Django authentication token through the request, to be received and stored by the React/Redux app in order to make API calls back to the Django application?

I've searched up online and all I can find is tutorials using a login page in the React/Redux app which is not what I want. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can use csrf token to send an api request. and in rest frame work you can use session authentication

Comment: Make an API request from where exactly? I'm trying to pass the token to the React/Redux frontend. I don't want people to have to sign in to the React/Redux front end

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest scenario, I guess you host both apps under the same domain, you could just create an endpoint that requires regular Django authentication and generate a token. In case of unauthenticated call to that endpoint, you would redirect to the Django login page.

Please provide more details about your setup, then I could propose something more specific.

Comment: By regular Django authentication do you mean basic authentication?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/ SessionAuthentication, I think you are already using it for your login form

Comment: If you want to manage your token manually you can use `djangorestframework-jw`